# JSON with different schemas for a single external table in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery, external-tables

Is there a way to set up an external table in BigQuery on a few JSON files (stored in Google Cloud Storage) with different schemas?
I would have files with the schemas:

| field_name | type | mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| laps | record | repeated |
| waypoints | record | repeated |
| col1 | string | nullable |
| col2 | string | nullable |
| col3 | integer | nullable |

| field_name | type | mode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| laps | record | repeated |
| waypoints | record | repeated |
| col1 | string | nullable |
| col2 | string | nullable |
| col3 | integer | nullable |
| col4 | float | nullable |
| col5 | timestemp | nullable |

so, the new attributes will be only added to the end.

Comment: May I request an expected output of the table ? Placing loading json file query documentation here for reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#sql

Comment: @NestorCenizaJr 
it should contain 5 columns (from col1 to col5)
and for the json that don't have attributes col4 and col5, there will be null

Comment: Also looking for a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for this. When creating the External Table in BQ you have to set ignore_unknown_values = true.

Unfortunately, I was using the BQ create table interface which does not include this option.

After carefully reviewing the [External Table documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_external_table_statement) I found out about this option.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `project-id.dataset.table_name`

WITH PARTITION COLUMNS

OPTIONS (

format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',

uris = ['gs://bucket/folder/dt=*.json'],

hive_partition_uri_prefix = 'gs://bucket/folder',

require_hive_partition_filter = false,

ignore_unknown_values = true);
```